# keyboard close after pressing a number in textformfield inside listview flutter

Tags: android, forms, flutter

I have a ReorderableListView that calls a function that generates cards with TextTormFields, two texts and one numeric, the problem is that when focused on the numeric textfield after pressing any character on the keyboard, the keyboard close.

```
Expanded(
              child: ReorderableListView(
                onReorder: _onReorder,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                children: List.generate(
                  itemsList.length,
                      (index) {
                    return _buildItemCard(itemsList[index],index,_numberController);
                  },
                ),
              )
      
_buildItemCard(Map item, int index){

return Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
    height: 200,
    key: Key(index.toString()),
    child: Card(
      elevation: 2,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colorPrimaryWhite,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.5),
          borderRadius: _borderRadius,
        ),
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Row(children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45,
              height: 100,
              child: TextFormWidget(
                L10n.of(context).field1Text,
                text: item["field1"],
                maxLines: 2,
                icon: Icons.description,
                validator: (text) {
                  bool result = Validator.isNotNullNorEmpty(text);
                  if (result) {
                    item["field1"] = text;
                  }
                  return result;
                },
                autovalidate: true,
                validationErrorText: L10n.of(context).formsFillThisFieldError,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45,
              height: 100,
              child: TextFormWidget(
                L10n.of(context).field2Text,
                text: item["field2"],
                maxLines: 2,
                validator: (text) {
                  bool result = Validator.isNotNullNorEmpty(text);
                  if (result) {
                    item["field2"] = text;
                  }
                  return result;
                },
                autovalidate: true,
                validationErrorText: L10n.of(context).formsFillThisFieldError,
              ),
            )
          ]),
          Row(children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.45,
              height: 80,
              child: TextFormWidget(
                "",
                text: item["field3"].toStringAsFixed(0),
                maxLines: 1,
                maxLength: 5,
                icon: Icons.attach_money,
                onChanged: (v, c) {
                  bool result = Validator.isPositiveDouble(v);
                  if (result) {
                    item["field3"] = double.parse(v);
                  }
                  setState(() {});
                },
                inputFormatters: [
                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(15),
                ],
                keyboardType:
                TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true, signed: false),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(flex: 1, child: new Container()),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              iconSize: 40,
              onPressed: () => _deleteDialog(index),
            )
          ],)
        ]),
      ),
    )
);
```

And TextfieldWidget is just an easy way to call textfields, basically this:

```
TextFormField _buildTextFormField() {
TextFormField field = TextFormField(
  controller: widget.controller ?? null,
  key: widget.localKey ?? null,
  validator: (value) {
    if (widget.validator != null) {
      return widget.validator(value) ? null : widget.validationErrorText;
    }
    return null;
  },
  onTap: widget.onTap != null ? ()=> widget.onTap(widget.controller) : null,
  onChanged: widget.onChanged != null ? (val)=> widget.onChanged(val, widget.controller) : null,
  enabled: widget.enabled ?? true,
  initialValue: widget.text ?? null,
  maxLength: widget.maxLength ?? null,
  autovalidate: widget.autovalidate ?? false,
  maxLines: widget.maxLines ?? null,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    icon: widget.icon != null ? Icon(widget.icon) : null,
    hintText: widget.hintText,
    labelText: widget.label,

  ),
  inputFormatters: widget.inputFormatters ?? null,
  keyboardType: widget.keyboardType ?? null,
  obscureText: widget.obscureText ?? false,
);
return field;
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a GlobalKeys list at the start of the class and added keys from the listview

```
Expanded(
          child: ReorderableListView(
            onReorder: _onReorder,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
            children: List.generate(
              itemsList.length,
                  (index) {
                _keys.add(GlobalKey<FormFieldState>());
                return _buildItemCard(itemsList[index],index,_numberController);
              },
            ),
          )
```

And used it in te TextFormWidget.